# A git diff for what's new/modified/deleted from my current branch

Tags: git, git-diff

I've been playing with `git diff` a little bit and I can't seem to find a way to compare two branches for new/modified/deleted files coming only from my branch.

Let's says we got `master` and `dev`, which is the branch I'm working on. I would like to `git diff` them but only get what I modified in dev compared to master.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
git diff --name-status master dev
```

See `git help diff` for a full explanation of all the possible flags at the beginning of each line, but the most frequent would be (A)dded, (D)eleted and (M)odified...

Edit: Actually, if you want to get only the changes made on `dev`, then the above command will work, but you don't want to compare `dev` to the current head of `master`, but to the place where `dev` diverged from `master`, which is generally the same as `git merge-base master dev`. So the above command would be changed to:

```
git diff --name-status $(git merge-base master dev) dev
```

Comment: Won't this shouw ALL differences between master and dev. Including new files created in master but not present dev?

Comment: Well, yes... But a file introduced on `master` but not on `dev` would show up as deleted. If you're only looking for changes made just on `dev`, then `git log` accepts the same `--name-status` option (e.g. `git log --name-status master..dev`) but you'll have to do some post-processing to combine the information from each commit - I don't think there's a single command to do exactly that...

Comment: Actually, scratch that last comment - updated the answer with what I think is the right solution...

Comment: right!
```git diff `git merge-base dev master`..dev --name-status```

does the job!